# What does $f\star g$ mean in this context?

Tags: measure-theory, notation

Context:

[image: context]

This is a problem set in measure theory and integration. I never came across this notation before.

Comment: Convolution....

Comment: $(f \star g)(t) =\int f(x) g(t-x) d \mu(x)$.

Comment: What's the context? If it's from a textbook, surely the notation is explained somewhere. If it's from a homework assignment, surely the lecturer who set the assignment is the person to ask.

Comment: @ZacharySelk Thanks I know what a convolution is. I encountered the concept some years ago.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I just found the problem set on the internet.